# Federation key issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-azure-federations

I have to design a database for customer with email id as login but since we have lots of data we need to use federation but since we cant have string or varchar or nvarchar as federation key I am stuck at what should I do. User will use email id to login. 
How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use varbinary column, and populate the varbinary column with the hash of the email address.

IMHO using an email address as a Federation key does not seem like a good design idea though

Comment: Yes, email address as a Federation key sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: What I was planning is to have a table in root DB which will have email and Id as field then the federation will start on Id field...Let me know your thoughts....Thanks...:)

Comment: That sounds ok if the federation is on the ID. I have a similar setup with an Organisation table and OrganisationId is the federation key.